# Invert colours with CSS on mouse over

Tags: html, css, colors, mouseover

I have all of my categories shown in white DIVs with blue icons/text on them. I would like to invert the colors on mouse over, making the background blue and the icons/text white instead.

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
    <div class="catbox">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cloud fa-3x" style="color:#337ab7;"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><h4>Clouds</h4></a>
        <span style="color: #aaa;">4 Listings</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've got the background working without any issue, however I am not sure how to apply a white color to the fa icons or the span text. I know this has to be simple but can't quite figure it out. My CSS as of now is...

```
.catbox {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 25px 10px;
    margin: 25px 0 10px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0.15em 0.35em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.135);
}

.catbox:hover {
    background-color: #337ab7;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

You have an inline style defined in `<i>`. This is the root cause of all the problem:

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cloud fa-3x" style="color:#337ab7;"></i></a>
<!-- ------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

God, didn't see that. You need to give `!important` like:

```css
.catbox:hover a i {
  background-color: #337ab7;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

The use of `!important` is very much discouraged. So use:

```css
.catbox a i {
  color: #337ab7;
}
.catbox:hover a i {
  background-color: #337ab7;
  color: #fff;
}
```

And change your HTML to completely remove the inline style:

```css
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cloud fa-3x"></i></a>
```

---

For the links, you have to explicitly inherit. Add this line of CSS:

```css
.catbox:hover a {
  background-color: inherit;
  color: inherit;
}
```

Or better, keep it like what you had before:

```css
.catbox:hover,
.catbox:hover a {
  background-color: #337ab7;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Since `<i>` is inside `<a>`, it'll take the colour.

Comment: It works for <a href="#"><h4>Clouds</h4></a> but not for the icon or the "4 Listings" text. Does the style being specified in the HTML tags override that in the stylesheet?

Comment: @BrettPowell Looks like it. Can you share the full demo so that we can find what's exactly overriding it?

Comment: @BrettPowell You have an inline style defined in `<i>`. God, didn't see that. You need to give `!important` like how I have updated in the answer.

Comment: @BrettPowell I am also updating the answer in a better way. Kindly check.

Comment: Updated it according to your recommendation above, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with below code

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
    <div class="catbox">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cloud fa-3x" style="color:#337ab7;"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><h4>Clouds</h4></a>
        <span>4 Listings</span>
    </div>
</div>

<style>

.catbox
{
    background: #fff;
    padding: 25px 10px;
    margin: 25px 0 10px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0.15em 0.35em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.135);
}

.catbox:hover
{
    background-color: #337ab7;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.catbox:hover > a
{
    color: #fff !important;
}
</style>
```